# Restoring Grub without live session

Tags: boot

I am looking for a way to restore GRUB *without using any live session*. I am trying to do it using [UNetbootin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lubi/files/Lubi/7.04.01/).

After successful UNetbootin installation, on reboot, it takes me to a menu to select between Windows or UNetBootin. Selecting UNetBootin takes me to a command line interface.

```
grub>
```

But, I am [supposed](http://sabza.org/fixing-grub-from-within-windows/) to get a menu selection interface.

Question is what commands should I follow to restore my Grub from command line?

### Solution

I used [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) to *chain load* from Windows to GRUB. Then I used [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to restore GRUB. After that I had to go back in windows and undo the changes made by EasyBCD. (Thanks @EliahKagan)

Comment: You cannot use UNetbootin to restore GRUB from Windows; in the unlikely event that this gives you anything working, it still will not be the same as an ordinary GRUB installation. Instead, see [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows) (we'll probably close this as a duplicate of that) or [Fixing a Broken System in GRUB2/Installing](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Fixing_a_Broken_System).

Comment: @EliahKagan Yes. But all those options requires another boot-able device, which  I don't have access right now and why do you think UNetBootin can't restore grub?

Comment: UNetbootin uses its own boot loader. Why do you think UNetbootin *can* restore GRUB?

Comment: Getting the picture now. I guess my concept isn't clear. Thanks!

Comment: But, none of those answers of the other question answer my question. I want to restore GRUB *without using any live session.*

Comment: You've asked specifically about restoring GRUB using UNetbootin here (originally without specifying that you wanted/needed to avoid using a live environment). So if you were to post a new question asking specifically how to do that, it will likely be kept separate and open, and perhaps answered. It would probably be very difficult to accomplish this, and most likely it would be far preferable to address whatever situation is preventing you from booting a live CD, DVD, or USB flash drive. But you can still ask, and if you want to find out how to do it, I'd encourage you to go ahead.

Comment: I found [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) does exactly what I am looking for. It has a personal version which is free to use.

Comment: @oamcreasy EasyBCD will *chain load* from the Windows boot loader *into* GRUB. It won't actually install GRUB to the Master Boot Record. Was your goal simply to make Ubuntu bootable again?

Comment: Yes :) But now that you say it, I would rewrite MBR again when Ubuntu will be up and running.

Comment: Good point--that does seem like a complete solution to the original problem you presented. If you're interested in [writing an answer for it](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) (it doesn't have to be really long or anything, just a complete statement of the procedure), I'd be quite willing to vote to reopen this (and to encourage others to do so as well). So if you want to do that, please let me know. (There is no obligation.)

Comment: Yes, I'd like to add it as an answer.